# C# application doesnt display google maps engine to edit maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, browser, visual-studio-2013, desktop-application

I created a C# desktop application on visual studio 2013.

I wish to display Google maps engine to edit the icons on the C# desktop application.
The Google maps when opened on the webbrowser control doest work. It has compatibility issues even if I've downloaded the latest Google chrome or internet explorer.
How can i get it to work??

How can i do this??

Comment: Going to need some of your code to work off of

Comment: If you were asked this question what do you think you'd need to solve the issue?.. What kind of application? winforms/wpf/asp.net? what does "doesn't work" entail? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: Hi Sayse, its a C# windows form application. I've researched the google API key, but i believe thats for the asp.net web applications/websites only.

Comment: Ralt. I currently don't have any code for the webbrowser. I've just created a simple application with a webbrowser control

Comment: Unless you change something in the registry, the WebBrowser control always uses IE6 compatibility mode.

Comment: Hi SLaks, how can i change the registry so it uses google chrome? I need the google maps engine to function well so that i can edit my maps from the application i've built.

Answer (score 0):

Add a registry key forcing browser emulation to a later version (IE 11 in this instance below)

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"YOURPROGRAMNAMEHERE"=dword:00002af8

Comment: I will want to generate some code so that i dont have to go into the registry and add a key every time someone else wants to use the application. On their PC.

Comment: You can write this in using C#, here is a great example of how to do so

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C